# Pokemon GO Lower Right Bar

Tags: pokemon-go

I saw that the lower right bar shows the distance but in what direction do you walk?

Answer (score 4):

You don't get a direction. It's kind of a "hot or cold" thing, you just walk around until you find it.

You can try using this strategy:

[image]

Comment: while the info in the link may be helpful, it is generally best to summarize the important information from it to avoid loss of information due to link decay

Comment: @Dragonrage The link refers to an Imgur mirror, so it's probably going to stay up as long as this post is viewed.  I've embedded the image into the post, however.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience:

1. Select a Pokemon to track from the lower right hand box.
2. Start walking in a direction.

If you're walking in generally the correct direction, the box will periodically pulse, and the steps left should count down after some steps.